# Distributed Storage for Access and Preservation

Tags: digital-preservation, distributed-systems, storage

My organization wants to maintain multiple copies of data in order to preserve access in the case of localized disasters as well as for the purpose of long term preservation. Are there accepted formal models for determining the appropriate variety of media (eg tape, disk) and their placement in the network? Are currently operating distributed solutions (eg LOCKSS) viable long term solutions for large collections of data?

Comment: This feels like an engineering question than a theory question. I recommend [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/).